# My network on the android phone isn't working what is the problem now

Tags: mobile-network

My phone since was reset because it kept showing unfortunately android has stopped every app I selected it said the app unfortunately has stopped now my issue is ever since then my phone's network doesn't work.  I can't connect with any network provider,  what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clean your cache, or if you are using CWM, try cleaning up DALVIK Cache

Answer (score -2):

Me also facing same problem on my phone earlier. i uninstall some apps from my smart phone and problem was resolved. so you can try this. uninstall some app from your android app.